# How to handle one Google Analytics Tag in all environments (DEV/TEST/PROD)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-filters

I want to handle a single Google Analytics Tag for all environments but wanted to track only production data.

As per Google Help in this link https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6311518?hl=en , it says create environments and track the data. But each environment had different Tag codes.

Do I require to install all tag codes to track environments data?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the environments in GTM, and insert the relative container in each environment (which is the same GTM ID but some parameters change). You can then make a lookup table for the analytics property ID based on environment. So if you are in production, send the data to your property, otherwise to a fake property.